# How to change the font and text color of the title of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to be change the font of the title to Avenir, and I want to make it white. Here is my code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20)!]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

This code only changes the color of the title, not the font. Additionally, I tried implementing this in the App Delegate File, but that did not work.

Here is what my UINavigationBar looks like:[image]

I want the title to have a font of Avenir as well. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems this is needed as well:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle       = UIBarStyle.Black // I then set the color using:

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor   = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 47/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1.0) // a lovely red

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // for titles, buttons, etc.

let navigationTitleFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20)!

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: navigationTitleFont]
```

Answer (score 15):

In case someone needs this in **Swift 4**:

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBarAppearance.barTintColor = .red
navBarAppearance.tintColor = .white
navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20)!]
```

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor does not impact my navigation title text colors in Xcode 10 and Swift 5, they remain black. I could not find how to update them with my theme.

Comment: @Vilmir you should use `titleTextAttributes` for title. `tintColor` is for UIBarButtonItems.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the styles to be applied through out the whole app add these lines in the AppDelegate.m file.

```
NSShadow* shadow = [NSShadow new]; 
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f); 
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Kelvetica Nobis" size:20.0f],
NSShadowAttributeName: shadow 
}];
```

**NSForegroundColorAttributeName** sets the Font color.

**NSFontAttributeName** sets a custom font face to the title text.

**NSShadowAttributeName** applies a nice shadow effect to the text, you can remove this part if you want.

Also in advance, you can add these line to hide the text that comes up in back button in action bar when you navigate to another view within the navigation controller.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
     setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-1000, -1000)
     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Hope this help your question :)

Answer (score 6):

Your code is OK you just need to set all of `titleTextAttributes` in one line:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white , NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)!]
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 5**:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20)!]
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 35)!]
```

Code here are for Title and Large title. you can also remove custom font if you want system font.

Answer (score 3):

I'm updating this for iOS 15.  If you have a scroll view that pushes something behind the Nav Bar it WILL change the NavigationBar background if you do NOT set "navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance".

So here is a simple config to set it for ALL of your views in ViewDidLoad of your main ViewController.

```
        // Set top Nav Bar behavior for ALL of app
    let standardAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    // Title font color
    standardAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    
    // prevent Nav Bar color change on scroll view push behind NavBar
    standardAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    standardAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = standardAppearance
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = standardAppearance
```

So the 'scrollEdgeAppearance' you can set title color, tint, NavBar color and the works.  The standardAppearance is what shows at loading.

Took me a while to figure this one out for iOS15.

You're welcome!   :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would just create an outlet and do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30)!]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have created all of my UI elements programmatically, without Interface Builder. So, this solution does not suit my needs.